# What does the meme "proof you can be a fruit and a vegetable" mean?

Tags: jokes, pun

I saw a rather offensive meme, and for that reason I will not post the picture here. If you want to see it, just google the quote in the title. I'll just explain it here.

It's a picture of one or more persons in a wheelchair, and the hbtq-flag is present. I assume it's from the Pride parade or something.

I understand the connection between vegetable and wheelchair, as explained in this answer: [What's "wheelchair" in a vegetable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/74063/114229)

But what does fruit mean here? Does that have something to do with hbtq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fruit (slang)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_(slang)) *Fruit and fruitcake, as well as many variations, are slang or even sexual slang terms which have various origins but modern usage tend to primarily refer to gay men and sometimes other LGBT people. Usually used as pejoratives, the terms have also been re-appropriated as insider terms of endearment within LGBT communities.*